# Почему <ul> не реагирует на padding?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужна помощь с меню — как бы ему не задавал величину `<ul>`, код не реагирует на паддинги. То же самое с `<li>`.
В общем, нужно просто посмотреть, почему меню не реагирует на padding:

```css
.container1 {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fucklogo {
  display: block;
}

.fuckmenue ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fuckmenue a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #898885;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.fuckmenue a:hover {
  background-color: #1f1f1e;
}

.fuckmenue ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0, 40px, 0, 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <title>Future site fucked up</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="fuckheader">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="fucklogo">
            <img src="img/ETS.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="fuckmenue">
            <button class="pirozhok"><img src = "img/if_th-menu-outline_216423.png"></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Потому что запятые там лишние - уберите. И четыре параметра в случае их дублирования писать не надо - достаточно два (для верха-низа и права-лева)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в записи `padding: 0, 40px, 0, 40px;` - запятые не нужны

```css
.container1 {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fucklogo {
  display: block;
}

.fuckmenue ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fuckmenue a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #898885;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.fuckmenue a:hover {
  background-color: #1f1f1e;
}

.fuckmenue ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <title>Future site fucked up</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="fuckheader">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="fucklogo">
            <img src="img/ETS.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="fuckmenue">
            <button class="pirozhok"><img src = "img/if_th-menu-outline_216423.png"></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```